# Dreamweaver shows inactive design button for php file

Tags: php, dreamweaver

I am using **Dreamweaver cs5** . It works normally for all file types except for php files.

Whenever I create or open a php file,Dreamweaver shows a inactive **Design** and **split** button on the menu and tab.Only code button is active...

Is there any solution to **enable or activate the design button** for php files..

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Php cannot be previewed as simply as html can, unfortunately, since it needs to be interpreted to run. It is possible to set up a testing server which will then link in with Dreamweaver and allow you to see the code you write visually, but this isn't as simple as turning a parameter on.

Check out http://www.adobe.com/devnet/dreamweaver/articles/setup_testing_server.html for information on how to achieve this.

Failing that, you could always rename your files to [filename].html while you're working on them? This would show the php code as plain text in the design view, but if you're happy with that then it's a simpler solution that could work for you.

Comment: The OP is having issues viewing the page in design/split mode. This does not require a testing server unless the user has "Live View" activated. That said, using the design mode without Live View (and a testing server) means NO PHP code will be executed. So unless I read the question wrong, this answer will not solve the OP's issue.

Comment: Ok, so I was slighty wrong (unsurprising since I don't have Dreamweaver on this PC to check), but why the downvote? I fail to see how my answer is not useful, in fact I think it's very relevant to the question even if it doesn't actually solve the direct problem. These answers are encouraged in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer .

Answer (score 0):

**PHP** is a server-side language, it is to be processed at the server-side and a resulting HTML is send to the client(A web-browser, generally), from where the page request originated.
Since `Dreamweaver` does not have any inbuilt PHP engine, or server capabilities it would be difficult(most probably impossible) to get an active view of your PHP page from `Dreamweaver` as it is, using only the capabilities of `Dreamweaver`.

So, to solve this you can set some external server like `XAMPP`,`WAMP`, etc... and create a project in `Dreamweaver` with the server settings specified, by doing this you should be able to get a Design view of your PHP code in `Dreamweaver`. For the exact steps to do this, please refer:
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/dreamweaver/articles/setup_php.html

**Courtesy:**http://forums.oscommerce.com/topic/386240-open-the-indexphp-in-design-view-in-dreamweaver-cs5/